# Composing a set of container classes and accessing them from a base

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

I'm trying to use `boost::mpl::inherit_linearly` to compose a container class using types provided by the user:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit_linearly.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace mpl = ::boost::mpl;

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create the container by chaining vectors
//////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Base {};

// Types provided by the user
typedef mpl::vector<int, char, double>::type myTypes;

typedef mpl::inherit_linearly<
    myTypes, 
    mpl::inherit<mpl::_1, std::vector<mpl::_2> >,
    Base
    >::type InheritedContainer;


// Function for accessing containers
template <typename T>
inline std::vector<T>& get_container(Base& c) {
    return static_cast<std::vector<T>& >(c);
}


// Some functions that manipulate the containers
//     NB: These functions only know about the Base and the types
//         they want to access

void my_int_func(Base& b) {
    get_container<int>(b).push_back(42);
}

void my_char_func(Base& b) {
    get_container<char>(b).push_back('c');
}

int main() {
    InheritedContainer container;
    Base& bref = container;

    my_int_func(bref);
    std::cout << "Int: " << get_container<int>(bref).back() << std::endl;

    my_char_func(bref);
    std::cout << "Char: " << get_container<char>(bref).back() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compile error I get is:

```
question.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >& get_container(Base&) [with T = int]’:
question.cpp:40:   instantiated from here
question.cpp:31: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Base’ to type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&’
question.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >& get_container(Base&) [with T = char]’:
question.cpp:44:   instantiated from here
question.cpp:31: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Base’ to type ‘std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >&’
```

Shouldn't `Base` be a base of whatever type is produced by `inherit_linearly`? And if so, shouldn't a `vector<int>` and the other vectors show up in the type hierarchy for static_cast to pull out?

Is there any other way to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Base` is a base class of `InheritedContainer`, but not of
`std::vector<int>`.
As we know, `std::vector` isn't defined as the following:

```
class vector : Base {...
```

You may expect the following inheritance:

```
class InheritedContainer : Base, std::vector<int>, ... {...
```

However, in this case, the cast from `Base` to `vector<int>` is a cross-cast,
so this cannot be done with `static_cast`.

As you may know, the following is allowed:

```
InheritedContainer container;
Base& bref = container;
InheritedContainer& iref = static_cast<InheritedContainer&>(bref);
std::vector<int>& vi = iref;
std::vector<char>& vc = iref;
```

If you can prepare `get_container`, `my_int_func` and `my_char_func`, probably the types
to which the `std::vector` will be specialized are known beforehand.
If so, I suppose it is pertinent to hold `InheritedContainer&` instead of `Base&`
all along.
If you have to cast `Base` to `vector<T>`, probably
RTTI(for example adding virtual function to `Base`) and `dynamic_cast` will enable
the cast.